# How can i create new widget that show departments hierarchy in odoo 13?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-13

I want to create a custom widget to show the departments hierarchy chart, and if there is a way to use the already existed `hr_org_chart` *-which used on employee form show underlying employees-* widget that will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hr.employee` is hardcoded in `hr_org_chart` so you can only show the employee organisation hierarchy.

You can create a new module based on `hr_org_chart`.

You will need to replace `hr.employee` model with `hr.department`
Replace `employee_id` with `department_id`
Remove all fields that do not exist in the `department` model.
Rename templates

I did a quick test and it worked.

Comment: do you mean i have to copy module hr_org_chart and modify it?